# Docker unable to find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient == 2.0.3

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pip

Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

```
#10 3.069 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3
```

when trying to run docker build --tag python-docker .

Docker file:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Requirements.txt:

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mysql==0.0.2
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysqlclient==2.0.3
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation for mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) you'll need to have `default-libmysqlclient-dev` and a compiler installed on the system, so if you install it before running pip install it should work (I tested it, but of course without your app code)

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt 
# Install required library libmysqlclient (and build-essential for building mysqlclient python extension)
RUN set -eux && \
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

You can also add the pip install to the first run (with `&& \`) so the whole setup stays in one image layer.

Comment: Awesome thank you! That worked. So I have to add the default-libmysqlclient-dev to the image first before running the pip install?

Comment: Yes adding the mysql dev package (and the compiler) has to be done before the pip install, but you can do with one RUN statement and add the pip install with && to the existing RUN statement.